# How to force migrations to create datetime2 fields instead of datetime

Tags: sql-server, laravel

I'm developing a laravel application accessing a sqlserver database, and I need my date fields to be `datetime2`. Problem is, if I tell the migration engine to create a datetime field like this:

```
$table->dateTime('myDateTimeColumn');
```

if will create a `datetime` field, not a `datetime2` field.

How can I force a `datetime2` column without having to change them all AFTER the migration (which sounds very sloppy)?

Answer (score 5):

Force a datetime2 by adding a precision int to the method creating the datetime column.

```
$table->datetime(4);
$table->timestamp(4);
$table->timestamps(4);
```

Using datetime(), timestamp(), or timestamps() without specifying an integer will make a `DATETIME` column type on SQL Server and now saving any dates using Laravel will break the code because a `DATETIME` column type allows only for 3 digits for the microseconds part. Laravel ***sometimes*** places 4 digits for the microseconds and thus needing `DATETIME2`.

I discovered the solution when I was reading Laravel's source file:

`Illuminate\Database\Schema\Grammars\SqlServerGrammer.php`

It contains this function:

```
    /**
     * Create the column definition for a date-time type.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Support\Fluent  $column
     * @return string
     */
    protected function typeDateTime(Fluent $column)
    {
        return $column->precision ? "datetime2($column->precision)" : 'datetime';
    }
```

---

I made a unit test case on GitHub too. https://gist.github.com/spacemudd/abfa7ef66d096f3f20796bf373df365b

That test fails when you don't specify a precision on migration methods creating datetime columns.

Answer (score 0):

In `Illuminate/Database/Schema/Grammars/SqlServerGrammar.php`

change the function `typeDateTime()` so it returns the `'datetime2'` instead of datetime.

And for the `typeTimestamp()` you could do the same thing!

Comment: Ok, but something which doesn't involve changing framework vendor code?

Comment: As far as i know, nope.

Comment: -1. Never change vendor code. If you REALLY need to change some file in Laravel's Database defaults drivers, you need to create your own database driver that extend the default built in driver.

Answer (score 0):

you can do the same `$table->addColumn('type','name')`

```
$table->addColumn('datetime','myDateTimeColumn');
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: This doesn't work. Laravel returns 'Call to undefuned method... SqlServerGrammer::typeDatetime2();'